# Container View - reorder child views

Tags: ember.js

Based on the docs, I'm able to rearrange child views A,B,C of a container view to C,A,B by doing a "removeObject(A/B/C)" followed by a "pushObject(C/A/B)". For larger sets (my actual example is currently 64), is there a possibly more efficient way (such as say, just modifying a couple of values in the existing child views array?  Although the remove/pushObject is probably just fine, given the relatively larger time for the actual UI re-render.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using an `ArrayController` in combination with a `CollectionView`, you could use `SortableMixin` support to order its content according to your needs. Then your collection rendering would be updated as needed without any intervention on your side.

You could, for example, bind the `sortProperties` property of you controller to reflect the sorting criteria to apply.

*(If you need further explanation, some code extract from your app will be welcome)*

Comment: I don't have a CollectionView, though some portions of the Container View *are* a collection. Your suggestions were enough to cook up a home grown scheme for binding the View to my data.  Thanks!

Comment: Did this answer replyed your question? If so, you should accept it, or at least upvote. Thks!